# How to properly use the returned value of this function? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am implementing a function inside a class I found related to ML. So I am able to call the function, however, I would further like to use the p-value (a.k.a what the function is theoretically returning: dfResults[1]). The problem is that when I calling the function, it is only returning the print statement that preceds the return, and not the actual value (that should be the 0.97 ish).

Below is my code. Any suggestions to solve this will be appreciated.

```
class StationarityTests:
    def _init_(self):
        self.pValue = None
        self.isStationary = None

    def ADF_Stationarity_Test(self, timeseries, significance=.05, printResults = True):
            #Dickey-Fuller test:
            adfTest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
            self.SignificanceLevel = significance
            self.pValue = adfTest[1]

            if (self.pValue<self.SignificanceLevel):
                self.isStationary = True
            else:
                self.isStationary = False

            if printResults:
                dfResults = pd.Series(adfTest[0:4], index=['ADF Test Statistic','P-Value','# Lags Used','# Observations Used'])
                #Add Critical Values
                for key,value in adfTest[4].items():
                    dfResults['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
                print('Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Results:')
                print(dfResults)
                return dfResults[1]
```

Implementation:

```
sTest = StationarityTests()
sTest.ADF_Stationarity_Test(mtum_df['Adj Close'], printResults = True)
print("Is the time series stationary? {0}".format(sTest.isStationary))
```

Output: **I would desire to get the print, but also mainly interested in being able to use the p-value (0.97ish) to perform further computations**.

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Results:
ADF Test Statistic         0.215912
P-Value                    0.973140
# Lags Used                8.000000
# Observations Used     1682.000000
Critical Value (1%)       -3.434244
Critical Value (5%)       -2.863260
Critical Value (10%)      -2.567686
dtype: float64
Is the time series stationary? False
```

Comment: I don't know that there's a need for the return. Isn't the p-value you want accessible via `sTest.pValue` after running `ADF_Stationarity_Test`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but what you want seems to simply assign the returned value to a variable and use it. `p_value = sTest.ADF_Stationarity_Test(mtum_df['Adj Close'], printResults = True)`